# resolve 'Can't export GPIO problem on Rpi using python script

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing a python application which is programming and testing atmel microcontrollers through a SPI port.

The application is running on RaspberryPi model 3B+ and I use the command line application 'avrdude' to do the job. I use subprocess.Popen() from within my python script and in general this runs just fine.

Sometimes, the SPI port gets in a blocked state. The avrdude application then typically reports something like 'Can't export GPIO 8, already exported/busy?: Device or resource busy'

One can observe the exported GPIO's by:

```
pi@LeptestPost:/ $ ls /sys/class/gpio/
export  gpio10  gpio11  gpio8  gpiochip0  gpiochip504  unexport
```

I get out of this situation by invoking:

```
pi@LeptestPost:/ $ sudo echo 8 > /sys/class/gpio/unexport
```

resulting in:

```
pi@LeptestPost:/ $ ls /sys/class/gpio/
export  gpio10  gpio11  gpiochip0  gpiochip504  unexport
```

So I can unexport them all and move on manually but I would like to have this automated in the application with the following code (after detecting the error in the avrdude output):

```py
    args = ['sudo', 'echo', '8', '>', '/sys/class/gpio/unexport']
    result, error = self.runCommand(args, wait=True)


    def runCommand(self, args, wait = False, outputFileStr = "", errorFileStr = "", workingDir = ""):
    # documentation:
    #class subprocess.Popen(args,
    #                       bufsize=-1,
    #                       executable=None,
    #                       stdin=None,
    #                       stdout=None,
    #                       stderr=None,
    #                       preexec_fn=None,
    #                       close_fds=True,
    #                       shell=False,
    #                       cwd=None,
    #                       env=None,
    #                       universal_newlines=None,
    #                       startupinfo=None,
    #                       creationflags=0,
    #                       restore_signals=True,
    #                       start_new_session=False,
    #                       pass_fds=(),
    #                       *,
    #                       encoding=None,
    #                       errors=None,
    #                       text=None)

        print("Working on executing command " + str(args))
        if (outputFileStr != ""):
            stdoutFile = open(outputFileStr,'w')
        else:
            stdoutFile = None
        if (errorFileStr != ""):
            stderrFile = open(errorFileStr,'w')
        else:
            stderrFile = None
        if (workingDir != ""):
            cwdStr = workingDir
        else:
            cwdStr = None
        try:
            if (wait):
                p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, cwd = cwdStr)
                print("started subprocess with PID " + str(p.pid))
                p.wait() # Wait for child process to terminate, This will deadlock when using stdout=PIPE or stderr=PIPE
            else:
                #p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdin = None, stdout = None, stderr = None, close_fds = True)
                p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdin = None, stdout = stdoutFile, stderr = stderrFile, close_fds = True, cwd = cwdStr)
                print("started subprocess with PID " + str(p.pid))
            (result, error) = p.communicate(timeout=15) # Interact with process: Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached.           
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
            sys.stderr.write("common::run_command() : [ERROR]: output = %s, error code = %s\n" % (e.output, e.returncode))
            return e.output, e.returncode
        except FileNotFoundError as e:
            self.master.printERROR("common::run_command() : [ERROR]: output = %s, error code = " + str(e) + "\n")
            return "error", str(e)
        except subprocess.TimeoutExpired as e:
            self.master.printERROR("Process timeout on PID "+ str(p.pid) + ", trying to kill \n")
            p.kill()
            outs, errs = p.communicate()
            return "error", str(e)
        if (outputFileStr != ""):
            stdoutFile.close()        
        if (errorFileStr != ""):
            stderrFile.close()
        return result, error
```

But that does not do the job (no error, not the wanted result). I can imagine it's related to how the process is started within its shell or environment - but that's beyond my knowledge.

Any idea how to get this working?

Note: the avrdude application is also called using the 'runcommand' method and running fine.

Comment: I found a way out myself; I added the statement in a separate shell script and called that one from subprocess.Popen. It was imperative to add a bash shebang in in hte shell scrpt - otherwise it wouldn't work neither.

Comment: shell script content:

Comment: #!/bin/bash
echo 8 > /sys/class/gpio/unexport
echo 9 > /sys/class/gpio/unexport
echo 10 > /sys/class/gpio/unexport
echo 11 > /sys/class/gpio/unexport
ls /sys/class/gpio

Comment: shell script saved as unexport.sh

Comment: and called in python script like         result, error = self.runCommand(args,shell=True,wait=False,outputFileStr="outputUnexport.txt", errorFileStr=(self.firmwareDir+ "errorUnexport.txt"),workingDir='/home/pi/leptestFirmwares/firmwares')

Comment: where args: args = ['/home/pi/leptestFirmwares/firmwares/unexport.sh']